# Typescript won't update to latest version (NPM)

Tags: windows, typescript, npm

today I wanted to install a newer version of Typescript since the one installed on this machine is 1.0.3.0 (issuing the command tsc --v)

When I type in `npm install -g typescript@latest` I get this output:

```
%APPDATA%\npm\tsc -> %APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
%APPDATA%\npm\tsserver -> %APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
%APPDATA%\npm
`-- typescript@2.3.2
```

(I replaced my full path to \Appdata\Roaming directory with %APPDATA% for the sake of readibility).

This leads me to think that I already have typescript@2.3.2 which appears to be the latest, but if I type in tsc --v again, I still see 1.0.3.0

How do I "force" the ugprade of TSC?

Thanks

Comment: How does your package.json look like?

Comment: I am trying to install it globally so I am in no project folder.

Comment: What does `where tsc` output? This is just a wild guess, but maybe your `PATH` is not set correctly? :-/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, this sure leads to the correct way!

Here's the output:

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.js
    %APPDATA%\npm\tsc
    %APPDATA%\npm\tsc.cmd

Obviously the first two lines are wrong, I removed them from PATH and now it's working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Sebastian Sebald, I found a solution:

The output of `where tsc` was this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.js 
%APPDATA%\npm\tsc 
%APPDATA%\npm\tsc.cmd
```

This lead to `npm` telling me that it had already installed `typescript@2.3.2`, but when I typed `tsc` I actually was using `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe`.

I removed `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0` from my `PATH`variable et voilat!

Thanks everybody.

Comment: mine was slightly different 
- where tsc:
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\tsc
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\tsc.cmd
- C:\Users\jfaqu\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
- C:\Users\jfaqu\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd
version 2.4.1 was found in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\`
version 2.3.2 was found in `%PROGRAMFILES%\nodejs\`
So I went into `%PROGRAMFILES%\nodejs\` and `npm install typescript@2.4.1` and it was fixed.